# Converting Pandas Timestamp to just the time (looking for something faster than .apply)

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

So if I have a timestamp in pandas as such:

```
Timestamp('2014-11-07 00:05:00')
```

How can I create a new column that just has the 'time' component?

So I want

```
00:05:00
```

Currently, I'm using `.apply` as shown below, but this is slow (my dataframe is a couple million rows), and i'm looking for a faster way.

```
df['time'] = df['date_time'].apply(lambda x: x.time())
```

Instead of `.apply`, I tried using `.astype(time)`, as I noticed `.astype` operations can be faster than `.apply`, but that apparently doesn't work on timestamps (AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'astype')... any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `.dt.time` see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/basics.html#dt-accessor) for some more examples of things under the `.dt` accessor.

```
df['date_time'].dt.time
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two `df1` and `df2`, each having `date` and `time` columns respectively.
Following code snippets useful to convert data type and comparing.

```
type(df1['date'].iloc[0]), type(df2['time'].iloc[0])
>>> (datetime.date, pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp)
type(df1['date'].iloc[0]), type(df2['time'].iloc[0].date())
>>> (datetime.date, datetime.date)
df1['date'].iloc[0] == df2['time'].iloc[0].date()
>>> False
```