# How can I create a datetime column without 'date' part?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe and there's a column named 'Time' in it like the below(HH:MM:SS:fffff).

```
>>> df['Time']
0        09:42:29:75284
1        09:42:29:95584
2        09:42:31:15036
3        09:42:35:15138
4        09:42:35:95491
5        09:42:43:55414
6        09:42:45:35866
7        09:42:46:74638
8        09:42:47:35582
9        09:42:47:74774
10       09:42:48:94582
...
Name: Time, Length: 18924, dtype: object
```

I want to change its type as datetime, in order to make it easier to calculate. Is it possible to change its type, using pandas.to_datetime, as datetime without date?

Comment: Sorry you just want the time component, as `str` or `datetime.time`? see related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000660/converting-pandas-timestamp-to-just-the-time-looking-for-something-faster-than

Comment: @EdChum good find - just needs the `format='%H:%M:%S:%f'` first...

Comment: @JonClements I'm not sure this is a dupe though, the OP wants `datetime` dtype which would make your deleted answer more relevant IMO

Comment: @EdChum Thank you for your answer! The column itself is a series of time components. (Hour:Minute:Second:Millisecond) The problem is that I can do any addition or subtraction with the column's current type.

Comment: I think @Jon's deleted answer `pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')` should work fine for you

Comment: @EdChum If I do this: `>>> df['Time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')` it yields `ValueError: time data ':45106' does not match format '%H:%M:%S:%f' (match)` error. I think it's because there are five digits for millisecond.

Comment: And if I do this: `>>> df['Time'][0] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'][0], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')`, the row automatically gets pseudo date `0  1900-01-01 09:42:29.752840  47.99     +1`

Comment: Do you have a row value that is just `':45106'` then it's a duff value, you can try `pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f', errirs='coerce')` to convert this to `pd.NaT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to `timedelta64[ns]` dtype:

Source DF:

```
In [164]: df
Out[164]:
              Time
0   09:42:29:75284
1   09:42:29:95584
2   09:42:31:15036
3   09:42:35:15138
4   09:42:35:95491
5   09:42:43:55414
6   09:42:45:35866
7   09:42:46:74638
8   09:42:47:35582
9   09:42:47:74774
10  09:42:48:94582

In [165]: df.dtypes
Out[165]:
Time    object   # <-------- NOTE!
dtype: object
```

Converted:

```
In [166]: df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time.str.replace(r'\:(\d+)$', r'.\1'),
                                    errors='coerce')

In [167]: df
Out[167]:
              Time
0  09:42:29.752840
1  09:42:29.955840
2  09:42:31.150360
3  09:42:35.151380
4  09:42:35.954910
5  09:42:43.554140
6  09:42:45.358660
7  09:42:46.746380
8  09:42:47.355820
9  09:42:47.747740
10 09:42:48.945820

In [168]: df.dtypes
Out[168]:
Time    timedelta64[ns]   # <-------- NOTE!
dtype: object
```

Comment: What's with the whole `.str` stuff there? What does that offer over `pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%H:%M:%S:%f').dt.time` ?

Comment: @JonClements, the essential difference is the dtype. `pd.to_datetime(df[1], format='%H:%M:%S:%f').dt.time` will return a string (object) dtype, which is the same as OP has right now - the only difference is `.` instead of last colon

Answer (score 1):

Please refer python [to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) documentation.

```
import pandas as pd        
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['09:42:29:75284','09:42:29:95584','09:42:31:15036']})

   df
Out[]: 
             Time
0  09:42:29:75284
1  09:42:29:95584
2  09:42:31:15036
```

You can convert this into datetime format by specifying format as follows:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
Out[]: 
0   1900-01-01 09:42:29.752840
1   1900-01-01 09:42:29.955840
2   1900-01-01 09:42:31.150360
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

but doing this will also add date 1900-01-01.

Comment: OP says 'without date'