# Add new column with time only in Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So i have this Dataframe that has been scraped from a website.What i want to achieve is to add a new column with only time in it as HH:mm each time it scrapes new data.
But the code i use gives data and time

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','Rick', 'John'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18, 26, 23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
  
df['time'] = pd.date_range('11/5/2020', periods = 6, freq ='2H')  
df
```

Data i have:

```
    Name    Age               time
0   Tom     20  2020-11-05 01:00:00
1   nick    21  2020-11-05 01:00:00
2   krish   19  2020-11-05 01:00:00
3   jack    18  2020-11-05 01:00:00
4   Rick    26  2020-11-05 01:00:00
5   John    23  2020-11-05 01:00:00
```

Result I want

```
    Name    Age       time
0   Tom     20       01:00
1   nick    21       01:00
2   krish   19       01:00
3   jack    18       01:00
4   Rick    26       01:00
5   John    23       01:00
```

As the data is scraped every 15 minutes I want to append the new data to it with the time without the need to add header again like below:

```
    Name    Age       time
0   Tom     20       01:00
1   nick    21       01:00
2   krish   19       01:00
3   jack    18       01:00
4   Rick    26       01:00
5   John    23       01:00
0   Tom     20       01:15
1   nick    21       01:15
2   krish   19       01:15
3   jack    18       01:15
4   Rick    26       01:15
5   John    23       01:15
```

Comment: Hey, did you remember to search StackOverflow for similar articles? there seems to be an identical one right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000660/converting-pandas-timestamp-to-just-the-time-looking-for-something-faster-than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly here is what you want.

```
lst_date_range = pd.date_range('11/5/2020', periods = 6, freq ='2H')
df['time'] = [date_time.strftime("%H:%M") for date_time in lst_date_range]
```

By using **.strftime("%H:%M")** could allow you to select only hour and minute.

From

```
    Name    Age               time
0   Tom     20  2020-11-05 01:00:00
```

To

```
    Name    Age       time
0   Tom     20       01:00
```

But I do not understand what you are asking for appending without the need to add header, please explain more if you need help here.